# A cobordism theory from Hirsch's "Differential Topology" (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, cobordism

The following is exercise 5 on p. 176 in Hirsch's "Differential Topology" (corrected 6th printing):

> Let $\eta = (p,E,B)$ be a fixed vector bundle over a compact manifold $B$, $\partial B = \varnothing$. An *$\eta$-submanifold* $(M,f)\subset V$ of a manifold $V$ is a pair $(M,f)$ where $M\subset V$ is a compact submanifold and $f$ is a bundle map from the normal bundle of $M$ to $\eta$ (this requires $\dim \eta = \dim V - \dim M$). Two $\eta$-submanifolds $(M_i,f_i)\subset V$ are $\eta$-*cobordant* if there is an $\eta$-submanifold $(W,f)\subset V\times I$ such that $\partial (W,f) = (M_0,f_0)\times 0 \cup (M_1,f_1)\times 1$ (using an obvious notation). The set of $\eta$-cobordism classes corresponds bijectively to the homotopy set $[V,E^*]$.

Notes: here $I = [0,1]$, $E^*$ is the Thom space (or one-point compactification) of $E$, and "bundle map" means linear isomorphism on each fiber (see p. 88 of Hirsch).

**Questions**: are there references where this type of cobordism is introduced and/or studied in further detail? Is "$\eta$-cobordism" standard terminology for this type of cobordism?

Comment: From the top of my head, this is in Tom diecks book, Stong's cobordism book, probably also in Rudyak's book, perhaps in Wall's differential topology

Comment: @ThomasRot many thanks. I found this in Sec. 21.2 of tom Dieck and in Sec. 8.1 of Wall's differential topology book. If you paste something as an answer I'll be happy to accept (if you want the points). Otherwise I'll likely do that myself if no one else chimes in.

Comment: Can't resist the delicious reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments this is in Tom Diecks book (section 21.2), and in Wall's differential topology (Section 8.1).